# Pandas months between function, np.timedelta does not work

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, datetime

There are a million results for how to find number of months between two columns in a pandas dataframe, and they nearly all say to use this:

```
(date_end - date_start) / np.timedelta64(1, "M")
```

This doesn't work in some instances though, I'm not sure if this is a bug or what, but here's my example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["2018-01-27"], "b":["2020-02-29"]})
(pd.to_datetime(df.b) - pd.to_datetime(df.a)) / np.timedelta64(1,"M")
```

This gives:

```
0    24.612903
dtype: float64
```

But that's not right, 2020-02-29 is more than 25 months after 2018-01-27. In fact if you switch to the same year, it recognizes this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["2020-01-27"], "b":["2020-02-29"]})
(pd.to_datetime(df.b) - pd.to_datetime(df.a)) / np.timedelta64(1,"M")
```

This gives:

```
0    1.064516
dtype: float64
```

Is there an explanation for this and/or a better way to get months between two months?

Comment: you first code return `25.068277` in colab(pandas 1.5.3)

Comment: and second `1.084211`

Comment: I'm on pandas 2.0.0

Comment: And numpy 1.22.3

Comment: @FObersteiner: Could you explain this: I can only find an add-method on DateOffset.

Comment: right, that doesn't solve the *actual* problem; maybe use periods? E.g. `pd.to_datetime(df.b).dt.to_period('M') - pd.to_datetime(df.a).dt.to_period('M')`

Comment: cannot replicate your results. Try to update pandas and numpy to the most current versions and provide some feedback if the problem is still existing on your end

Comment: Using to_period doesn't fit my needs, it would show that January 31st to February 3rd is a full month, my final goal is to get complete months I floor the result of this comparison so I'd want that to return 0 but I'd want January 20th to February 28th to be 1. I'm actually trying to replicate a function in a different language so I'm actually not 100% what I want for example Janaury 31st to February 28th to show. I'll try upgrading but I'm using relatively new versions of both pandas and numpy, I guess I may end up having to implement the algorithm myself, but will likely be much slower.